# Websphere 8.5 an application start/stop notification

Tags: java, websphere

How do I know that a application deployed in Websphere 8.5 has started/stopped. Intention is to send an email to a team when application is started/stopped.

So far I could not able to move any step further as I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a singleton ejb marked as "startup" bean, where you use @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy for managing the lifecycle of your app.

```
@javax.ejb.Startup
@javax.ejb.Singleton
public class Lifecycle {


    @javax.annotation.PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        //send mail
    }

    @javax.annotation.PreDestroy
    public void shutdown {
        // do something else :)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. My application is REST based (Spring). I just added this class (as-is) but somehow on application startup it never reached to this class. Not sure if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get application status in application scope, you can write a script which periodically checks  application logs to find any start/stop logs, then send mail to recipients.

```
WSVR0217I: Stopping application: ApplicationName
WSVR0221I: Application started: ApplicationName
```